# Is there a way to extract or capture html5 video frames without playing or seeking?

Tags: javascript, html, video, canvas

Is there a way to extract or capture frames to canvas from html5 video at specific points without playing or seeking the video? ( no jQuery or external libraries )

could I add a second instance of the video and set it as hidden then seek and capture frames I wanted. if so how can I insure the video has seeked to position and showing an image before drawing the frame to the canvas?

Comment: Question#2: If your browser supports `MediaElement.readyState` then you can (1) do your seek, (2) listen for `loadeddata` event, (3) and if `readyState>=2` then you can safely play() at least 1 frame. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/readyState

Comment: @markE you're right but I'd remove the "listen for `loadeddata` event" part : If the video is already with `readyState = 4`, this event won't fire anymore, you'd better just listen to the `playing` event since OP wants only one frame. But anyway, you should add this as an answer since it's the correct one  :)